# Code Gets stuck forever on Selenium Driver Definition at times

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

my code gets stuck on the Driver definition line every once in a while (say 1 out of 4 or so times). I was wondering if there is a way to raise a timeout error after a time threshold of the code running and retrying if it exceeds the threshold, so I wouldn't have to restart the code block in the event that the definition takes forever to run.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= service, options=options)
```

```
service = Service(executable_path=r'/usr/bin/chromedriver')
options = Options()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service= service, options=options)`
```

I would appreciate you lot's thoughts and do let me know if anyone faced the same issue and have ever since found a way to fix it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try their the latest?

```
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
```

Specification says like this is new feature for the chrome > 109 version
And they also say that the oldest options.add_argument("--headless") may lead to errors.